# Oracle sql listagg based on another column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, listagg

I am new to Oracle SQL and i need to deal with a task like below..

I have atttached an image here and what I needa do right now is, using SQL to show the result like right hand side from left hand side..

I need to listagg the Column 2 (C2) and Column 3 (C3), based on Column 1 (C1)
If C2 and C3 just got one record and no duplicated records, 
then the result shows like the first row: 4316, Orange shipper 1, Hong Kong, China.
However there are some tricky cases like 4343/4403/4406 in C1.
C2 may have duplicated records but C3 doesnt have, vice versa.

I tried to use rank_over, then the result becomes the left hand side in the attached image.

```
SELECT t1.number AS C1,
       t2.shipper AS C2,
       rank() over (partition BY t2.shipper
                    ORDER BY t1.number) AS rank_over_c2,
       t2.venue AS C3,
       rank() over (partition BY t2.venue
                    ORDER BY t1.number) AS rank_over_c3
FROM table1 t1,
     table2 t2
```

But after that I have no idea how i can get the result like the right hand side in the attached image..

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcAsN.png) is here:
Left hand side is the original columns and data, I would like to get the result like the right hand side

Comment: Your question seems to be unstructured. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask question which can be easily answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT c1, listagg( c2, ', ' ) within group ( order by c2 ) as C2
   FROM ( select distinct c1, c2 from c1c2 )
   Group by c1
) x 
JOIN (
   SELECT c1, listagg( c3, ', ' ) within group ( order by c3 ) as C3
   FROM ( select distinct c1, c3 from c1c2 )
   Group by c1
) y
using( c1 )
```